# Unable to read csv file on Google Colab

Tags: python, pandas, csv, google-colaboratory

I'm trying to read a sample dataset from Kaggle on Google Colab. I've tried to read the csv file by uploading it to my Google Drive as well as by loading it to my ipynb using the Kaggle API.

This is the command I'm trying:

```
df=pd.read_csv("/content/quality/MiningProcess_Flotation_Plant_Database.csv",usecols=need_cols,dtype=data_dir)
```

For some weird reason, the error message is from the very first command I've given.

**TypeError: data type 'quality-prediction-in-a-mining-process' not understood**

Since then, I've tried to rename the folder. I've also tried reconnecting the runtime.

[image: Screenshot of the error]

Comment: What are you passing as dtype and what do you understand it should be?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try removing dtype and use this instead:

```
df=pd.read_csv("/content/quality/MiningProcess_Flotation_Plant_Database.csv",usecols=[0,1])
```

need_cols should be like [0,1]

Comment: Hey! Thank you so much. This seems to fix the problem. Why does dtype cause this error?

Comment: @AswinBravissimo Usually csv files can only contain strings, integers and floats so dtype can only be one of those types